# Fullcalendar load events from DB in Java

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'm following this tutorial https://mohittare.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/using-fullcalendarwithjava/ for showing events in FullCalendar and I'm getting message:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/CalendarJsonServlet?start=1445814000&end=1449442800&_=1446654395750 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I supposed to put in **events:**? which path? or how to find it? Here is my code from .jsp file:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
```

$.getScript('http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js',function(){

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    firstDay: 1,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: "/CalendarJsonServlet"
  });
})
```

```
<div class="container">
<hr>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

here is my CalendarJsonServlet.java class:

```
    package com.wirecardproject.project;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class CalendarJsonServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    List l = new ArrayList();

    CalendarDTO c = new CalendarDTO();
    c.setId(1);
    c.setStart("2015-11-28");
    c.setEnd("2015-11-29");
    c.setTitle("Task in Progress");

    CalendarDTO d = new CalendarDTO();
    c.setId(2);
    c.setStart("2013-07-26");
    c.setEnd("2013-08-28");
    c.setTitle("Task in Progress");

    l.add(c);
    l.add(d);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(new Gson().toJson(l));
}

}
```

and CalendarDTO.java:

```
    package com.wirecardproject.project;

public class CalendarDTO {
public int id;
public String title;
public String start;
public String end;
public String color;

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(String start) {
    this.start = start;
}

public String getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public void setEnd(String end) {
    this.end = end;
}
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Post the relevant java code, complete stacktrace and explain what is going wrong. Given that you are tagging the question with Java, I don't see any Java-code or stack-trace.

Comment: That code is JavaScript. The CalendarProject/CalendarJsonServlet is part of the .js in the fullCalendar.js file. Your Java calls will use that to help build your events in the calendar.

Comment: Lenusska, where did you include Jquery?

Comment: I have Jquery in my .jsp file like this:

    <script type="text/javascript"
 src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
CalendarDTO d = new CalendarDTO();
c.setId(2);
c.setStart("2013-07-26");
c.setEnd("2013-08-28");
c.setTitle("Task in Progress");
```

to

```
CalendarDTO d = new CalendarDTO();
d.setId(2);
d.setStart("2013-07-26");
d.setEnd("2013-08-28");
d.setTitle("Task in Progress");
```

The second object is D not C

Answer (score -1):

One of the solution that worked for me is in the `CalendarJsonServlet` create both the methods `doGet()` and `doPost()`. In `doGet()` call the `doPost(request,response)` and put your code/logic in `doPost()`.